# Is it possible to clear ' from strings transmitted through input field

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have a input field as below

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" name="keywords" id="CG_searchterm_global" class="search-field" title="Enter search criteria">
```

And user can type in anything. However, if user enters input as `"Hello W'Orld"`, I want to transmit everything except `'`. That is I do not want the `'` to be transmitted through form. How can I do that? Maybe through a jquery that clears the strong transmitted of any `'` ? Is that possible....

Comment: You can use plain JavaScript and `.replace()` for that. No jQuery needed.

Comment: ↑↑↑ Or maybe avoid user to be able to type it in input field. That way user knows what will be transmitted

Comment: Thanks.. But I want that to happen before input field transmits data to backend

Comment: You know, you will need to sanitize the values on the server anyway, regardless of whether you sanitize with javascript. The user can bypass javascript.

Comment: @Dilbert but javascript replace is used client side anyway and ya, you still need to sanitize it server side

Answer (score 1):

You can override the forms submit function and remove the `'` there:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
   search = $('#CG_searchterm_global').val();
   search = search.replace(/'/g, '');
   $('#CG_searchterm_global').val(search);
   $(this).submit();
});
```

But it is probably better to either validate and not allow `'` or remove it server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStr = myStr.replace(/'/g, '\"');
```

javascript using ***replace*** method of it

Or if you are using c# the just replace it although if you develop your structure parameterized the that will not be a issue i think

Comment: oh sorry sorry i changed

Comment: But will this execute before input field transmits data

Comment: Ya but you can call this onclick of your submit button

Comment: Do it like this `$('id of your input').val( $('id of your input').val().replace(/'/g, '\"'));`